# What formula do I use to work out a percentage of tasks complete in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have wrote a "y" in the cells where the task has been completed and a "n" where they havent. These are in `D5:CI5`.

I want to work out their percentage in cell C5.

I looked up other answers but none had the formula I was looking for. If someone knows how to do this please help!

Answer (score 1):

D5:CIF isn't a valid range, assuming you mean D5:CI5 then try this formula which gives "y" answers as a percentage of all those completed

`=COUNTIF(D5:CI5,"y")/COUNTA(D5:CI5)`

format result cell as precentage